# Do I need to use AlarmManager.cancel() method?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm wondering - why do I need an [AlarmManager.cancel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel(android.app.PendingIntent)) method, if I can just call [cancel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#cancel()) method of corresponding `PendingIntent` and it would also work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the alarm and the pending intent are different things. Your alarm just triggers your pending intent at "x" time. If you cancel the pending intent but not your alarm then the alarm will be triggered anyway but the action will not occur because the pending intent is cancelled. Think of the alarm as the trigger and the pending intent as the action.

Comment: Ok, but if I cancel PendingIntent, alarm also wouldn't be performed, right?

Comment: Alarm should be triggered anyway, but the action wouldn't be performed because the pending intent is in a cancelled state. Keep in mind that the pending intent isn't only for alarms but for other things like notifications. That's why alarm manager also has a cancel method.

Comment: When the alarm is triggered it dispatch the pending intent. What happens then isn't alarm manager business (if the action doesn't occur because the pending intent is cancelled for example).

Comment: In the notification system service case for example. If you set a pending intent to be triggered when the user tap the notification, then the pending intent will be triggered BUT if the pending intent is in a cancelled state then the action will not occur also.